# TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments?

Tags: python

I have recently started python and tried to write simple program but this error keep showing up. What am i doing wrong?

```
class Store:

 def __init__(self,name, id, price):
    self.name=name
    self.id=id
    self.price=price
    print("------------")

Store()
item1=Store(Chips, 10, 500)
```

OUTPUT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aqsa/PycharmProjects/untitled5/list.py", line 8, in <module>
    Store()
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'name', 'id', and 'price'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `Chips`? If it's a string, it needs to be written with quotes: `"Chips"`.

Comment: It means that in `Store()` missing the arguments. Get rid of this

Comment: Honestly the error message is very clear. `Store.__init__` requires 3 arguments, but you gave it none in `Store()`.

Answer (score 8):

You define your constructor for the `Store` class as

```
 def __init__(self,name, id, price):
    self.name=name
    self.id=id
    self.price=price
    print("------------")
```

Then call it with `Store()` which expects a constructor like

```
 def __init__():
    self.name='default'
    self.id=0
    self.price=0
    print("------------")
```

Get rid of the `Store()` call!

Also, did you mean to call the other constructor as `Store('Chips', 10, 500)`?

Giving us

```
class Store:

 def __init__(self,name, id, price):
    self.name=name
    self.id=id
    self.price=price
    print("------------")

item1=Store('Chips', 10, 500)
```

Comment: thank you for replying. I am sorry i thought that __init__ method takes the value of the parameters from the obj created and pass them to the parameters. that is what i try to do. i made item1 as obj of the class store and (chips,10,500) are the values for the parameters define in the __init__ methods.